# Usage of UNC paths in XeTeX Documents

Tags: xetex, paths

Is it possible to use UNC paths in a XeTeX document?

Comment: I know that Xe(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX can handle both the "normal" forward-slash and "Windows-style" backslash directory separators. No idea (being blessed not having to deal with UNC paths on my own system) if Xe/LuaTeX also know what to do with `\\` network-type instruction paths.

Comment: Something like `\input{\\Server\Shared\WGroups\Network\file.tex}` will definitely not work. Can you give some examples? Did you try changing the ``\`` (backslash) into `/` (forward slash)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just convert all the `\` into `/`; `//server-name/dir/dir/file` should work (at least it does with TL2011).