# How to use UNC path

Tags: verbatim, urls

I struggle a bit with UNC paths in latex.

My paths looks something like

> \\server\folder\folder

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48566/usage-of-unc-paths-in-xetex-documents). Which recommends to change \ to /. Thats not really a solution.

I put the path in a verbatim block which work but ignores the text flow.
My other 'solution' is to replace every \ with `\textbackslash{}`

The question I have is: Is there any recommended or best practices way to deal with UNC paths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to print the `path`s. If so, you may need this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}

\begin{document}
  \path{\\server\folder\folder}

  \path{\\server\my folder\folder}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I searched. And now I feeling a bit stupid because path is kinda obvious.

Comment: @Sirl33tname Glad my guess is correct. I know that feeling as it happens to me too. It's OK. :-)